# Learning Smooth Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

This may come off being a silly question but I was curious if it would be possible for me to learn smooth manifolds from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and learn multi-variable analysis along-side it. My current knowledge consists of real analysis (single variable), topology, abstract algebra, linear algebra.

From other posts I've read that it is recommended to understand multi-variable analysis before understanding manifolds. But I want to know if I can just learn the necessary as I move through lee's book.

Comment: If you read Baby Rudin ch. 9 and do the exercises you should be OK.

Comment: IMHO Baby Rudin is about the worst place to read multivariable analysis, but so be it. Regardless, you need multivariable analysis (including the derivative as a linear map, inverse and implicit function theorems) before you start wrestling with manifolds. You should know the statement of the change of variables theorem for integrals, although you need not know the proof.

Comment: @TedShifrin I understand that you have a YouTube channel that includes your class lectures of multi-variable calculus, but sadly your book "Multi-variable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multi-variable Calculus, and Manifolds" is a bit on the pricey side. Would James Munkres "Analysis on Manifolds" or Hubbard and Hubbard's "Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach" work alongside your lectures?

Comment: I sadly have no control over the price of books. I am not a fan of Hubbard's book; I wrote mine because my students couldn't deal with his. Munkres's book is fine. You mostly need a source of exercises; the lectures are pretty much self-contained. (Both Hubbard and I purport to teach linear algebra and multivariable calculus to students who don't already know it computationally. Munkres is writing an analysis book for students who've had multivariable calculus and single-variable analysis.)

Answer (score 2):

Putting whether or not you *can* aside. You *really* should learn multivariable analysis first. The logical order is

1. Linear functions on linear spaces ((finite dimensional) Linear Algebra)
2. Non-linear functions on linear spaces which can be approximated by linear functions (Multivariable Calculus)
3. Non-linear functions on non-linear spaces which can be approximated by linear functions and linear spaces (Smooth Manifold Theory)

Now you certainly can learn the third one without the other two, since it is a generalization. But, and this is important, Lee's book assumes that you've already done steps 1 and 2 and are comfortable with that material. So do yourself a favor and instead of going back and forth between multivariable calculus and Lee's book, do multivariable first and then go through Lee's book. You aren't saving yourself any time by trying to interleave the learning.

Of course, nobody will stop you from picking up Lee's book and trying to work through it. We are just saying you will understand things much better if you have a solid understanding of multivariable calculus. For example, you should know:

- the inverse function theorem
- how derivatives are linear maps and how second derivatives are bilinear maps
- the topology of $\mathbf{R}^n$
- how to actually work with multivariable functions (this is huge because a lot of examples rely on this knowledge)

---

On the other hand, there are textbooks that develop the theory of mutivariable analysis along side of manifolds. Two examples are Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" and Munkres's "Analysis on Manifolds". The key differences are: these are aimed at the undergraduate level and they don't assume prior knowledge of multivariable calculus.

Comment: Very late to the party. But in addition to those two books, I want to recommend: [Advanced Calculus of Several Variables by C.H. Edwards](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-Several-Variables-Mathematics/dp/0486683362/), [Advanced Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-Differential-Approach-Birkhäuser-ebook/dp/B00HWUNKHG/), and the classic but monstrous [Advanced Calculus by Loomis and Sternberg](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf).